python pandas dataframe select rows with ternary operator
I have what has to be considered a syntax question. I am doing some data scrubbing. My data contains date time fields. The date is always present, but sometimes the time is missing. Like this:
3/1/2023 11:03 AM
4/8/2022 10:21 AM
7/19/2012
7/12/2021
4/16/2024 7:02 AM

So, if the full colon (:) is missing, I want to concatenate  00:00 AM.
I expected this to work:
dfAssetMeter_a['lastReadingDTFixed'] = dfAssetMeter_a['LASTREADINGDATE'].astype(str) if dfAssetMeter_a['LASTREADINGDATE'].astype(str).find(':') > 0 else dfAssetMeter_a['LASTREADINGDATE'].astype(str) + ' 00:00 AM'  

but it didn't work.
This works, however:
def fixDateTime(dateStr_in):
    return dateStr_in if dateStr_in.find(':') > 0 else dateStr_in + ' 12:00 AM'

dfAssetMeter_a['lastReadingDTFixed'] = dfAssetMeter_a['LASTREADINGDATE'].apply(fixDateTime)

Questions:

What would be the more correct “Python” way to do this?
Could someone provide the correct syntax for the first method?


Thank you all for the replies below.  Good Stuff.

Anybody care to to take a shot at providing the correct syntax for the ternary operator.  Thanks and best regards to all

You can use pandas.to_datetime with format='mixed'.
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "LASTREADINGDATE": [
            "3/1/2023 11:03 AM",
            "4/8/2022 10:21 AM",
            "7/19/2012",
            "7/12/2021",
            "4/16/2024 7:02 AM",
        ]
    }
)

df["lastReadingDTFixed"] = pd.to_datetime(df["LASTREADINGDATE"], format="mixed")

     LASTREADINGDATE  lastReadingDTFixed
0  3/1/2023 11:03 AM 2023-03-01 11:03:00
1  4/8/2022 10:21 AM 2022-04-08 10:21:00
2          7/19/2012 2012-07-19 00:00:00
3          7/12/2021 2021-07-12 00:00:00
4  4/16/2024 7:02 AM 2024-04-16 07:02:00


This looks like the simplest , most straight forward solution.    Thanks

Whatever approach you use is fine, as long as it is intuitive.  However you could just directly update the data with something like this:
df.loc[~df['time'].str.contains('\:'), 'time'] += ' 12:00AM'


OK I am going to have to take that statement apart character by character.

~ means not, so wherever the string does not contain : add the time to the original value.  The \ is just there as an escape character, and it would probably work without it

A more straightforward way to accomplish this could be to use where
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html
Let's say we have the following data frame:
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['date'] = ['3/1/2023 11:03 AM', '4/8/2022 10:21 AM', '7/19/2012']

The following assignment will accomplish the task that you described.
df['fixed'] = df['date'].where(df['date'].str.contains(':'), df['date'] + ' 00:00 AM')

Result:
                date               fixed
0  3/1/2023 11:03 AM   3/1/2023 11:03 AM
1  4/8/2022 10:21 AM   4/8/2022 10:21 AM
2          7/19/2012  7/19/2012 00:00 AM


This is a general approach to emulating the ternary operator. But the answer by @e-motta is a better approach to normalizing the time data—you can avoid the need to write your own normalization.

You don't need NumPy, Pandas has its own where: df['fixed'] = df['date'].where(df['date'].str.contains(':'), df['date'] + ' 00:00 AM')

Thank.   This helps with the "learning"
